# Necessary user, group and permissions for core updates

Tags: updates, filesystem

What user, group and permissions of files and folders I need for core updates?

### Test setups

I tried everything [the manual](http://codex.wordpress.org/Updating_WordPress#One-click_Update) recommended me to. Here are some test setups I used, the setup was recursively used on the WordPress installation.

- Case A: The owner has read/write permissions.
- Case B: The owner and group have read/write permissions.

Every permission case above was tried with the following user and group setup.

1. Owner: Apache | Group: Apache
2. Owner: Apache | Group: FTPuser
3. Owner: FTPuser | Group: FTPuser
4. Owner: FTPuser | Group: Apache

### Test results

- **1A**:

  ```
  Could not create directory.
  ```

  ---
- **1B**:

  ```
  Could not create directory
  ```

  ---
- **2A**:

  ```
  Could not create directory.
  ```

  ---
- **2B**:

  ```
  The update cannot be installed because we will be unable to copy some files. This is usually due to inconsistent file permissions.: wp-admin/includes/update-core.php
  ```

  ---
- **3A**:

  ```
  Warning: touch(): Unable to create file /home/FTPuser/domains/domain.name/public_html/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/wordpress-4.tmp because Permission denied in /home/FTPuser/domains/domain.name/public_html/wordpress/wp-admin/includes/file.php on line 155
  Warning: unlink(/home/FTPuser/domains/domain.name/public_html/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/wordpress-4.tmp): No such file or directory in /home/FTPuser/domains/domain.name/public_html/wordpress/wp-admin/includes/file.php on line 457
  Download failed.: Destination directory for file streaming does not exist or is not writable.
  ```

  ---
- **3B**:

  ```
  Warning: touch(): Unable to create file /home/FTPuser/domains/domain.name/public_html/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/wordpress-4.tmp because Permission denied in /home/FTPuser/domains/domain.name/public_html/wordpress/wp-admin/includes/file.php on line 155
  Warning: unlink(/home/FTPuser/domains/domain.name/public_html/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/wordpress-4.tmp): No such file or directory in /home/FTPuser/domains/domain.name/public_html/wordpress/wp-admin/includes/file.php on line 457
  Download failed.: Destination directory for file streaming does not exist or is not writable.
  ```

  ---
- **4A**:

  ```
  Warning: touch(): Unable to create file /home/FTPuser/domains/domain.name/public_html/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/wordpress-4.tmp because Permission denied in /home/FTPuser/domains/domain.name/public_html/wordpress/wp-admin/includes/file.php on line 155
  Warning: unlink(/home/FTPuser/domains/domain.name/public_html/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/wordpress-4.tmp): No such file or directory in /home/FTPuser/domains/domain.name/public_html/wordpress/wp-admin/includes/file.php on line 457
  Download failed.: Destination directory for file streaming does not exist or is not writable.
  ```

  ---
- **4B**:

  ```
  The update cannot be installed because we will be unable to copy some files. This is usually due to inconsistent file permissions.: wp-admin/includes/update-core.php
  ```

  ---

These updates always have been a big issue for WordPress, I would like to clarify this let's find a general solution! The installation is hosted on a CentOS 6.6 server running with DirectAdmin.

### EDIT:

The custom configuration  at wp-config.php I used for these tests, contain the following:

```
$root='public_html';
define('FTP_USER','username');
define('FTP_PASS','password');

$addr=$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];
$name=$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
$host=$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$https=$_SERVER['HTTPS'];
$protocol=(!empty($https)&&$https!=='off'||$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']===443)?'https://':'http://';
$abspath=(strpos(getcwd(),'/wp-admin')!==FALSE)?substr(getcwd(),0,strrpos(getcwd(),'/wp-admin')):getcwd();
$relpath=substr($abspath,strrpos($abspath,$root)+strlen($root));
define('WP_HOME',$protocol.$host.$relpath);
define('WP_SITEURL',$protocol.$name.$relpath);
define('FS_CHMOD_DIR',(02755&~umask())); //FOR CASE A
define('FS_CHMOD_FILE',(0664&~umask())); //FOR CASE A
define('FS_CHMOD_DIR',(02775&~umask())); //FOR CASE B
define('FS_CHMOD_FILE',(0664&~umask())); //FOR CASE B
define('FS_METHOD','ftpext');
define('FTP_BASE',$abspath);
define('FTP_HOST',$addr);
```

Comment: Is PHP running as CGI or an Apache module?

Comment: @TheDeadMedic The Server API is "Apache 2.0 Handler".

Comment: @TheDeadMedic Why is this important? I've added my config maybe this will narrow it down.

Comment: It's important if you're using `direct` for `FS_METHOD`, as CGI will need suPHP or similar. Have you tried direct? So long as PHP can run as the same owner as your files, direct is always the most reliable & efficient filesystem method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeahh! I finally found a solution!

The trick was to set all files and folders their ownership and group to the apache user. Make sure you've an directory for temporary storage and you need to have the `../wp-content/upgrade/` directory as well. Than at your `wp-config.php` this is the only thing I'm not aware about of the compatibility of it. But you'll need constant `FS_METHOD` set to `direct` like @TheDeadMedic suggested.

To make live easier I created a bash script what is pretty easy to use, it will get everything into place except the `wp-config.php` you'll have to add the following to this file by yourself.

```
// Some static information, so fill this in correctly.
$root='public_html';
define('FTP_USER','<username>');
define('FTP_PASS','<password>');

// This is dynamically configured. You won't have to edit.
$addr=$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];
$name=$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
$host=$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$https=$_SERVER['HTTPS'];
$protocol=(!empty($https)&&$https!=='off'||$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']===443)?'https://':'http://';
$abspath=(strpos(getcwd(),'/wp-admin')!==FALSE)?substr(getcwd(),0,strrpos(getcwd(),'/wp-admin')):getcwd();
$relpath=substr($abspath,strrpos($abspath,$root)+strlen($root));
$tmppath=substr($abspath,0,-(strlen($relpath)+strlen($root))).'tmp';
define('WP_HOME',$protocol.$host.$relpath);
define('WP_SITEURL',$protocol.$name.$relpath);  
define('FS_CHMOD_DIR',(02755&~umask()));
define('FS_CHMOD_FILE',(0644&~umask()));
define('WP_TEMP_DIR', $tmppath);
define('FS_METHOD','direct');
define('FTP_BASE',$abspath);
define('FTP_HOST',$addr);
```

Than the bash script, this works as following: bash script.sh **$1 $2**

- **$1**: Choose an action to run

  - help: Show how to use this script.
  - config: Configure an already existing WP installation correctly, one what is installed in the CURRENT directory.
  - new: Install a new WP CMS in the CURRENT directory and than configure it correctly.
- **$2**: the public directory name, so we can detect from where files are private. The default and also most common is `public_html` leave this parameter empty if your server uses this as default as well.

And now the bash script itself! :D

```
# If requested install WP
if [ "$1" = new ]; then
    wget https://wordpress.org/latest.tar.gz
    tar -xvf latest.tar.gz
    mv -f wordpress/* .
    rm -rf wordpress/ latest.tar.gz
fi
if [[ "$1" = help || -z "$1" ]]; then
    echo "Usage: install.sh \$1 \$2"
    echo "\$1: default=config, new=install new WP."
    echo "\$2: default=public_html, *=root folder (must be a parent)."
else
    # Define root directory
    if [ ! -z "$2" ]; then
        root=$2
    else 
        root='public_html'
    fi

    # Define root path
    dir=`pwd -P`
    tmp=${dir%%$root*}"tmp"

    # Define apache user
    APACHE_USER=$(ps axho user,comm|grep -E "httpd|apache"|uniq|grep -v "root"|awk 'END {if ($1) print $1}')

    # Create missing directories
    if [ ! -d "$tmp" ]; then
        mkdir "$tmp"
        chown -R "$APACHE_USER":"$APACHE_USER" "$tmp"
    fi
    if [ ! -d wp-content/upgrade ]; then
        mkdir -p wp-content/upgrade
    fi

    # Setup group and ownership for the installation
    chown -R "$APACHE_USER":"$APACHE_USER" wp-* index.php xmlrpc.php .htaccess

    # Make sure the chmoding is correct
    find wp-* index.php xmlrpc.php .htaccess -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
    find wp-* -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;

    # Remove unwanted WP files
    rm -f license.txt readme.html
fi
```

**TIP**: To make it available everywhere on the system, then just put it in /usr/local/bin/ when that's done you're able to just run `$ <script name> **$1 $2**`. Make sure the "script name" is unique.