# Plugin updates change folder permissions

Tags: plugins, permissions

On one client WordPress site, when I update any plug-ins, all files and directories within that plug-in get their permissions automatically set to 766 - which means they aren't accessible by the website. I then have to go in manually and change permissions. I've not come across this behaviour on any other website.

Does anyone know why this might be happening, and how I can prevent it?!

Many thanks

Comment: do you have the same problem when the wordpress core is updated ?

Comment: That sounds like it could be an issue with what Apache user "owns" the files. You might find help in this answer - https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/177036/necessary-user-group-and-permissions-for-core-updates#answer-191859

Comment: Kaperto - hah, I don't know. I think this problem arose since the client site was moved to a new server. That's a good point though - shall avoid updating WP core till I've resolved it!

WebElaine - thanks, I'll try and update this thread when I've seen what happens...

Answer (score 0):

So in the end it was two lines in wp-config.php that somehow had gotten changed:

define( 'FS_CHMOD_DIR', ( 0755 & ~ umask() ) );
define( 'FS_CHMOD_FILE', ( 0644 & ~ umask() ) );

... had been set to 0766